# IDの重複チェック

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

insertの際にIDが重複しているかいないかの確認がしたいです。

現在ソースは下のようになっておりますが、何故か重複していない値をいれても重複していますとHTMLで表示されてしまいます。

この画像の重複をクリックするとHTMLに遷移して、重複しています、または重複していませんが表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

サービスクラス

```
public User doubleCheck(String id) {

    User u = userRepository.getById(id);

    if (u.getId().equals(id)) {
    //if (null != u) {
        return u;
    }
    return null;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,String>{

  List<User> findBynameLike(String name);
```

```
@PostMapping("double")
  String DoubleCheck(@RequestParam String id,
Model model) {

    User u = sevi.doubleCheck(id);
    //model.addAttribute("u", u);
    if (null != u) {
        String msg = "重複してるよ";
        model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        return "double";
    }
    String msg2 = "重複してないよ";
    model.addAttribute("msg2", msg2);
    return "double";
}
```

```
</head>
<body>
<span th:text=${msg}></span>
<span th:text=${msg2}></span>
</body>
</html>
```

サービスクラスを以下の様にしましたら
いけました。アドバイスありがとうございました。

```
  public User doubleCheck(String id) {
    try {
      User u = userRepository.getById(id);
      u.getName();
      return u;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
```

Comment: タイトルは質問内容が読み取れるよう、もう少し具体的なものを心掛けてください。

Comment: `getById` の実装に問題があるのではないでしょうか。`id` をキーにして取得できたなら `id` は同じはずですし、取得できなかったなら `u.getId()` が `NullPointerException` を送出すると考えられます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 引数に指定した `id` を持つ `User` が既に登録されている場合はその `User` を返す
- まだ登録されていない場合は `null` を返す

という仕様ならば、次の実装で良いかと思います:

```java
    public User doubleCheck(String id) {
        return userRepository.getById(id);
    }
```

重複登録時に何か追加で処理をしようとしているのであれば、最初に `getById` の戻り値の `null` チェックを行うのが良いでしょう:

```java
    public User doubleCheck(String id) {
        User u = userRepository.getById(id);
        if (u == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // 追加の処理
        // ...

        return u;
    }
```

単に真偽値を返せばよいのなら `existsById` も利用できます:

```java
    public boolean doubleCheck(String id) {
        // id が既に存在しているのなら(つまり、重複登録しようとしているのなら) true
        return userRepository.existsById(id);
    }
```